# From YearMonth(yyyy-MM) to YearMonth(yyyy-MMMM)

Tags: java, date

I have a variable:

```
YearMonth date;
```

where inside standing `"2016-07"`, for example.

I want it to be still YearMonth, but with `"2016 july"`(note , there's no "-" separator), or, even better, `"2016 luglio"`, that is italian Locale.

How to do it?

***UPDATE***

I tried with JackDaniels's method. It could actually work, as it gives me a string(`str`) with the right format of date. But I need to put that string again into my YearMonth variable. I tried with:

```
myVariable = YearMonth.parse(str);
```

but it returns me an error: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014 gennaio' could not be parsed at index 4`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try the updated code? It has both the example for parsing and then for formatting dates is two different time zones. Try editing the code, and and show us what you tried, so we can help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new **DateTimeFormatter** to parse and format YearMonth directly and use Locale to set the locale you need. 
**Don't use SimpleDateFormat. That is part of the old Date API.**

Try running the code to see if this is what you want in [Codiva online compiler IDE](https://www.codiva.io/p/8b4cb781-5a22-43a7-a3e7-d65a8f3c6fe3?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sof-answers).

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2016, 7);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMMM",
    new Locale("it", "IT"));
System.out.println(yearMonth.format(formatter));
```

Full working code in [Codiva](https://www.codiva.io/p/8b4cb781-5a22-43a7-a3e7-d65a8f3c6fe3?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sof-answers).

Comment: yearMonth.format(formatter) will give me a string. I tried to do 
myVariable = YearMonth.parse(str), but it will give me an error:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014 gennaio' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: Use this method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-
Updated the sample code for parsing also in the Codiva link.

Comment: not working. You can see yourself it returns "2014-01", not "2014 january"

Comment: I thought you would figure it out from, the combination of yearmonth classes, parse and format methods. In any case, updated the code. Try it.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Or still need help?